# Proper use of template when type interface is slightly different

Tags: c++, templates

I will have a class function to operate close-to-exactly-same operations on two possible parameter types, say foo(TypeA * t) and foo(TypeB * t)
There are two scenarios: 1) the entire function is equivalent, the interface of the two types are exactly the same, I think I can use one just a template definition:

template 
  void foo(T * t)

2) the interface will be slightly different, in the function we should use t->x in TypeA  in place for t->y in TypeB, all the rest of the function should be equivalent. Is there a good/clean way without writing two functions or function specification?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) in C++17, so it will be something like this:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T * t)
{
   if constexpr (std::is_same_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>, TypeA>)
      t->x();
   else
      t->y();
   // the rest of your function
}
```

Alternatively, you can simply factor out the parts that differ into another function for which you create 2 template specializations.

EDIT: In this particular case it might work with simply `std::is_same_v<T, TypeA>` since you can't have pointer to a reference. But in general it's best to add `std::decay_t<T>` or `std::remove_reference_t<T>` like I did above.